# AWS SageMaker is not authorized to perform: ecr:CreateRepository on resource: *

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, scikit-learn, dockerfile, amazon-sagemaker

I am creating my own Docker image so that I can use my own models in AWS SageMaker. I sucessfully created a Docker image using command line inside the Jupyter Notebook in SageMaker ml.t2.medium instance using a customized Dockerfile:

```
REPOSITORY            TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
sklearn               latest              01234212345        6 minutes ago       1.23GB
```

But when I run in Jupyter:

```
! aws ecr create-repository --repository-name sklearn
```

I get the following error:

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateRepository operation: User: arn:aws:sts::1234567:assumed-role/AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole-12345/SageMaker is not authorized to perform: ecr:CreateRepository on resource: *
```

I already set up SageMaker, EC2, EC2ContainerService permissions and the following policy for EC2Container but I still get the same error.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "sagemaker:*",
        "ec2:*"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any idea on how I can solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried modifying the SageMaker execution role to have AWS:ecr:CreateRepo Permissions?

Comment: Yes, I did it and it didn't work.

Comment: I will check it again, maybe I have overlapping permissions for SageMaker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem. We must set a permission at SageMaker Execution Role as following:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ecr:*"            ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]}
```

Comment: You don’t have to have such a permissive role. You can restrict it to specific actions (CreateRepo, for example) and specific resources.

Comment: I have the same issue. Add permission **AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess** solved my problem, because this permssion has under the hood `"Action": [ "ecr:*" ]`