# Trying to BUILD & PUSH 'tfrecord-processing' Docker image AWS - User denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-ecr

I am following this tutorial right here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/training-and-deploying-models-using-tensorflow-2-with-the-object-detection-api-on-amazon-sagemaker/ and I am trying to build and push `tfrecord-processing` docker image by executing following command:

```
!sh ./docker/build_and_push.sh $image_name
```

Everything seems to go fine until very end:

```
Step 6/7 : COPY code /opt/program
 ---> 68bc931b454c
Step 7/7 : ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "/opt/program/prepare_data.py"]
 ---> Running in 68fa1cac7cae
Removing intermediate container 68fa1cac7cae
 ---> 769c873f471c
Successfully built 769c873f471c
Successfully tagged tfrecord-processing:latest
Pushing image to ECR 382599840224.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/tfrecord-processing:latest
The push refers to repository [382599840224.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/tfrecord-processing]

f2a18981: Preparing 
0de55568: Preparing 
2361f986: Preparing 
4b3288d4: Preparing 
e55f84c6: Preparing 
b0f92c14: Preparing 
cf4cd527: Preparing 
c1f74e01: Preparing 
9e4b0fc9: Preparing 
e3b79e0a: Preparing 
e43735a0: Preparing 
3918ca41: Preparing 
768f66a4: Preparing 
d332a58a: Preparing 
f11cbf29: Preparing 
a4b22186: Preparing 
afb09dc3: Preparing 
b5a53aac: Preparing 
c8e5063e: Preparing 
e4b0fc9: Waiting g denied: User: arn:aws:sts::382599840224:assumed-role/AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole-20210306T151543/SageMaker is not authorized to perform: ecr:InitiateLayerUpload on resource: arn:aws:ecr:us-east-2:382599840224:repository/tfrecord-processing
```

Here is the code for `build_and_push.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# This script shows how to build the Docker image and push it to ECR to be ready for use
# by SageMaker.

# The argument to this script is the image name. This will be used as the image on the local
# machine and combined with the account and region to form the repository name for ECR.
image=$1

if [[ "$image" == "" ]]
then
    echo "Usage: $0 <image-name>"
    exit 1
fi

# Get the account number associated with the current IAM credentials
account=$(aws sts get-caller-identity --query Account --output text)
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]
then
    exit 25
fi

# Get the region defined in the current configuration (default to us-west-2 if none defined)
region=$(aws configure get region)
fullname="${account}.dkr.ecr.${region}.amazonaws.com/${image}:latest"

# If the repository doesn't exist in ECR, create it.
aws ecr describe-repositories --repository-names "${image}" > /dev/null 2>&1
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]
then
    aws ecr create-repository --repository-name "${image}" > /dev/null
fi

# Get the login command from ECR and execute it directly
$(aws ecr get-login --region ${region} --no-include-email)

# Build the docker image locally with the image name and then push it to ECR
# with the full name.
cd docker/

echo "Building image with name ${image}"
docker build --no-cache -t ${image} -f Dockerfile .
docker tag ${image} ${fullname}

echo "Pushing image to ECR ${fullname}"
docker push ${fullname}

# Writing the image name to let the calling process extract it without manual intervention:
echo "${fullname}" > ecr_image_fullname.txt
```

I guess I need to set some roles for my user, but not sure which or where. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering if the problem you are seeing is due to:

```
# Get the login command from ECR and execute it directly
$(aws ecr get-login --region ${region} --no-include-email)
```

This is supposed to spit the docker login command and execute it directly (as the comment says).

You may want to try it outside of the script and see if it generates any error or constructive message.

A reason why this may not work is because this cli command (`aws ecr get-login`) is only available in the CLI v1. If you are using the CLI v2 version then you need to use the `aws ecr get-login-password` command. [See here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/registry_auth.html) for full syntax.

[UPDATE] I reached out to the team that wrote the blog/repo and they fixed the command to reflect the AWS CLI v2 syntax. Apparently what happened is that the SM Notebook was updated to include the new CLI after the blog was published and that command needed an update. The repo should have the "fix" now.

Answer (score 0):

Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/50684081/11262633, add `Elastic Container Registry` to the policy `AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionPolicy` in IAM.

I had to manually edit the JSON - the Visual Editor did not save my change.